# Create tab and add N rows with pygsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

I want to create an empty tab via pyghseets and add N rows, like I would do with the following button:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this in pygsheets?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

My base code is the following:

```py
import pygsheets

client = ### # Please use your client.

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet to create" # Please set your sheet name.
N = 10000
sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)

# Create sheet_name and add N rows below
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a code you're working on?

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```py
import pygsheets

client = ### # Please use your client.

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = "Sheet to create" # Please set your sheet name.
N = 10000
sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
sh.add_worksheet(sheet_name, rows=N)
```